# Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._basetostring'

Tags: node.js, npm

I cant seem to ran any commands against `> npm` including `> npm help` ,`> npm uninstall` or `> npm upgrade`

the full error is

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._basetostring'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\lodash.pad\index.js:9:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

I cant run `> npm install lodash._basetostring` or npm anything

Comment: npm -v ? or try running as root? 'sudo npm -v'

Comment: I am running it through powershell as administrator. `> npm -v` gives the same error

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall node? It looks like your installation folder was somehow corrupted or something.

Answer (score 0):

Tried reinstalling and running 'npm cache clean' but even that didn't work, so here's my solution:

Delete all files from, you may want to backup the files first but those are corrupted anyway.

```
<user profile directory>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

and then try running npm command, if this works then there's no need to reinstall, just install npm modules using

```
npm install -g <package names>
```

Otherwise uninstall node.js, empty above stated folder and then install node.js.

Don't forget to update npm

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```